# bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6

Tags: classpath, maven-3, jvm-hotspot

I am upgrading my application from java 1.6 to 1.7. When I try to build using Maven 3.2.1, my build fails with below error msg:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project my-app5: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] could not parse error message: warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
```

I am using java 1.7 hotspot and previously I was using 1.6 jrockit. My application is multi module and few modules compile and build as usual, this module failed.

I have set java home properly and **mvn --version** shows below output:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T23:07:52+05:30)
Maven home: C:\Users\me\Maven3\apache-maven-3.2.1-bin\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\jdk17051\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Trying the result from here: [Maven compile error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293062/maven-compile-error?rq=1)

Comment: Added <source>1.7</source> <target>1.7</target> to my compiler plugin config. Didnt help...still getting same error msg and build is failing

Comment: possible duplicate of [warning: \[options\] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816423/warning-options-bootstrap-class-path-not-set-in-conjunction-with-source-1-5)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it using below configuration in my compiler plugin:

```
<fork>true</fork>
<executable>${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
<compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion>
<source>1.7</source>
<target>1.7</target>
```

This will use the JDK which you have defined in your `JAVA_HOME` environment property.

Answer (score 6):

Quote from [this post](http://vanillajava.blogspot.nl/2012/02/using-java-7-to-target-much-older-jvms.html):

> Java 5.0 and 6 used to have poor support for compiling classes to
>   target older versions of Java. It always supported the previous
>   version, but often no more. Even if you could compile for previous
>   version, you had to be careful not to use functionality which did
>   exist in the previous versions.

You should either include `-Xbootclasspath` when using javac:

```
javac -Xbootclasspath:/path/to/jdk6/rt.jar -target 1.6 -source 1.6 Main.java
```

or compile using `-target 1.7` (or higher of course):

```
javac -target 1.7 -source 1.7 Main.java
```

or use `javac` of jdk 6:

```
/path/to/jdk6/bin/javac Main.java
```