# gradle refers java 6 even though my java home is aim to java 8

Tags: java, build, gradle, java-8

I run  `./gradlew clean build`

and i get this error:

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6

/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/java/UsersServer/src/test/java/linqmap/users/jms/UsersServerAccessPropUserNameTest.java:163: error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6

        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

                                                     ^

  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

1 error

1 warning

:compileTestJava FAILED



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':compileTestJava'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.



BUILD FAILED
```

even though I see my java home is java 8.

where else do i need to configure java 8 ?

```
➜ myServer  echo $JAVA_HOME      

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

my gradle.build:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
//
//    configurations.all*.exclude(group: 'com.sun.jersey', module: 'jersey-bundle')
//    configurations.all*.exclude(group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module:'jackson-databind')


    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'

    compile 'com.google.inject:guice:4.0-beta5'
    compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.18.3'
    compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:1.18.3'
```

Comment: You've configured the compilation task to use the option `-source 1.6`. And you're using JDK8 to compile, and using syntax available since Java 7. That's why gradle complains. Post your build.gradle.

Comment: added. and i have `sourceCompatibility = 1.8
`

Comment: The build fails for compileTestJava. Have you configured this task somehow? Do you also use the diamond operator in non-test source files?

Comment: it all used to work till i updated my intellij

Comment: What does that have to do with IntelliJ. Gradle doesn't care about your version of IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've explicitly set the source compatibility.

Try adding:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
```

Comment: i have `sourceCompatibility = 1.8
`

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543885/bootstrap-class-path-not-set-in-conjunction-with-source-1-6) SO answer.

Comment: Are you explicitly exporting/setting JAVA_HOME=/...path.../to../jdk1.6.0_xx in the $GRADLE_HOME/bin/gradle file?